# Jqplot charts shows black canvas on safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jqplot

I developped jqplot charts and i have black canvas only on safari on osx. Does anyone experiences the same thing ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I am look for a css trick that remove the black overlay

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue. I was my virtual machine running OSX that was the problem. I tested on a real Mac and it works perfectly.